# Perforce-P4 sync query-new work space

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-branch-spec

I have synced files around 1 Tb from one server to another and set up P4, but I have a different workspace in the new server so if i initiate a p4 sync in new server, Will it add only the difference or will it duplicate the files?(source remains the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created a new workspace, and P4 doesn't know that you have the files already existing on your new environment, it will pull over all of those files.

If you kept the same workspace name, (by default) it would pull over only "new" files (because it thinks you already have the files you previously synced).

Comment: Thanks.So if I do p4 sync -f ,will it duplicate the files?

Comment: Yes, if you do p4 sync -f, it will rewrite those files (you won't be left with duplicates, but you will unnecessarily pull those files over anew.

Comment: Ok.I did a p4 sync -f and completed much faster than the rsync.But initially it deleted some files since i cant verify,Will it delete some files that are not in work space?

Comment: No, p4 sync -f will not delete files that are not in your workspace. If you *want* to clean up the files in a particular directory "p4 clean" will do that for you (I found that out, uh, accidentally).

Answer (score 3):

If the workspace map is the same as the old client, and there have been no changes, you can do a p4 sync -k. This updates the metadata on the server, without doing the file transfers. If there have been changes, you'll have to force sync those files to get the correct revision.

Comment: Do "p4 clean" after your "p4 sync -k" to fix up the changed files.